# Need a dynamic range/bucket in SSAS and would like to use it as a column in the power bi matrix

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

In a SSAS cube, I have a table called Workload with ID and CATG as columns.
[image: Workload]
and another table Hierarchy with ID and Name
[image: Hierarchy]

I need output in the following way

[image: Output]

*Range = number of DISTINCT CATG from Workload table.

I need the count of IDs from Workload based on the Range.

Can you please help me with this?

I tried to create Range as a column in the Workload table. But as it is a column and not a metric, we cant apply any other filters from other tables. If I create it as a metric, I cant use it as a column in pbi matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an additional unconnected SupportTable, where you need to store range Label, Min and Max value per range:

[image]

```
CountOfIDs =  var _rangeMin = SELECTEDVALUE(SupportLabel[MinVal]) var
_rangeMax = SELECTEDVALUE(SupportLabel[MaxVal]) return COUNTROWS( FILTER( SUMMARIZE('Workload','Workload'[ID],"distvalperid", calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT(Workload[CTRG]) )), [distvalperid] <=
_rangeMax && [distvalperid] >= _rangeMin) )
```